# Can we make Communication between android UI and spring,struts,Hibernate integration application?

Tags: android, spring, hibernate, struts

I am new to android application development.

I developed one login application. In this application I designed UI screen using `android sdk`, I enter the username,password and send those values to servlet using `HttpClient`,`HttpPost` classes for authentication. After completing the authentication I print authentication message on android UI screen.

But now my requirement is ,I wants to use Spring,Hibernate and Struts integration instead of Servlets and jdbc code, Is it possible to use?

please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You can use `xml` or `json` for communication.

As you would be using Spring you can follow : **REST API based approach** with your server application so that even if you want to develop same UI application in iPhone or any other device, you can make request to your single web service.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is! Here is a good project your can check out:

http://www.springsource.org/spring-android